# apache login page preventing ajax call

Tags: apache, passwords, angular5

I'm attempting to send data to an endpoint over POST and am running into an issue with the page since its protected by apache's htpasswd file. I am willing to have the user login to go to the page, however the issue is that with the ajax request that isnt happening. the login box does not show, so im unable to get it to log in. Im using angular 5 and the HTTPClient from @angular/common/http.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the username and password and use the function btoa() to encode it, then send it off in the authorization header with every get and post, it solves the issue.

example:

header.set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password));